# SQL Server Pivot Sum By Day Grand Total

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot, crosstab

The query work except the total sum of local amount. I can used sum `IIF` or case when  to calculate the sum of the local amount as usual but I would like to know how it works using a SQL Server pivot.

The first query  are pivot and with roll up and I want this below query union to it and given the output of grant total.

```
   DECLARE @financialYear INT;
   DECLARE @financialPeriod INT;

   SET @financialYear = 2013;
   SET @financialPeriod = 7;

   SELECT chartOfAccountCategoryDescription,
          chartOfAccountDescription,
          coalesce([1], 0) AS [1],
          coalesce([2], 0) AS [2],
          coalesce([3], 0) AS [3],
          coalesce([4], 0) AS [4],
          coalesce([5], 0) AS [5]
    ,coalesce([6], 0) AS [6]
    ,coalesce([7], 0) AS [7]
    ,coalesce([8], 0) AS [8]
    ,coalesce([9], 0) AS [9]
    ,coalesce([10], 0) AS [10]
    ,coalesce([11], 0) AS [11]
    ,coalesce([12], 0) AS [12]
    ,coalesce([13], 0) AS [13]
    ,coalesce([14], 0) AS [14]
    ,coalesce([15], 0) AS [15]
    ,coalesce([16], 0) AS [16]
    ,coalesce([17], 0) AS [17]
    ,coalesce([18], 0) AS [18]
    ,coalesce([19], 0) AS [19]
    ,coalesce([20], 0) AS [20]
    ,coalesce([21], 0) AS [21]
    ,coalesce([22], 0) AS [22]
    ,coalesce([23], 0) AS [23]
    ,coalesce([24], 0) AS [24]
    ,coalesce([25], 0) AS [25]
    ,coalesce([26], 0) AS [26]
    ,coalesce([27], 0) AS [27]
    ,coalesce([28], 0) AS [28]
    ,coalesce([29], 0) AS [29]
    ,coalesce([30], 0) AS [30]
    ,coalesce([31], 0) AS [31]
    ,coalesce([Total], 0) AS [Total] FROM (
    SELECT 'Total' AS chartOfAccountCategoryDescription
        ,' ' AS chartOfAccountDescription
        ,ISNULL(DATENAME(DAY, generalLedgerDate), 'Total') AS theMonth
        ,ABS(localAmount) AS items
    FROM generalLedger
    WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, generalLedgerDate) = @financialYear
    ) AS s
    PIVOT(SUM(items) FOR theMonth IN (
            [1]
            ,[2]
            ,[3]
            ,[4]
            ,[5]
            ,[6]
            ,[7]
            ,[8]
            ,[9]
            ,[10]
            ,[11]
            ,[12]
            ,[13]
            ,[14]
            ,[15]
            ,[16]
            ,[17]
            ,[18]
            ,[19]
            ,[20]
            ,[21]
            ,[22]
            ,[23]
            ,[24]
            ,[25]
            ,[26]
            ,[27]
            ,[28]
            ,[29]
            ,[30]
            ,[31]
            ,[Total]
            )) AS p
```

Comment: Are you creating report? If so, it's better to handle such PIVOT/Total logic in reporting tools.

Comment: ya report..  but this is pure query will be output in excel not using crystal report or jasper report or srss